# Question about a proof by contradiction observation involving mutually exclusive disjunctions

Tags: logic

I encountered an exercise that provided the reader with the following information:

*Statement 1*. $0\lt x\lt y \rightarrow x^n \lt y^n$

*Statement 2*. $0\lt y \lt x \rightarrow y^n \lt x^n$

*Statement 3*. trichotomy on the reals

and then asked:

> Prove that $[x,y \gt 0 \land x^n = y^n] \rightarrow x=y$

The method (contradiction) I employed was to negate $[x,y \gt 0 \land x^n = y^n] \rightarrow x=y \quad$ into $\quad x,y \gt 0 \land x^n = y^n \land x\neq y$

From $x,y \gt 0 \land x^n = y^n \land x\neq y$...and noting that $x \neq y \iff x \lt y \lor y \lt x$...we arrive at:

$x,y \gt 0 \land x^n = y^n \land [x \lt y \lor y \lt x]$

Glossing over the last few details, we arrive the contradiction of:

$x^n = y^n \land [x^n \lt y^n \lor y^n \lt x^n]$

Therefore: $[x,y \gt 0 \land x^n = y^n] \rightarrow x=y \quad$ **must be true**

---

In the above proof, it struck me that there was a particular *structure* embedded within the claims that allowed the proof by contradiction to work "smoothly". Specifically, both the antecedent and consequent of Statement 1, Statement 2, and the claim-to-prove were all subject to a "one and only one" behavior.

For example: $x^n \lt y^n \lor y^n \lt x^n \lor x^n=y^n$ is a true statement...but only one can be true at any time.

Similarly: $x \lt y \lor y \lt x \lor x=y$ is a true statement...but only one can be true at any time.

The two above comments are a byproduct of *trichotomy on the reals*, but I imagine what I observed can be generalized to other statements that exhibit this special type of disjunction where only one of the constituent propositions can be true at any time.

The idea of a bijection crossed my mind when I thought of how there appears to be a 1-1 pairing between the antecedents and the consequents. i.e.

[image: Proof]

**Is there any greater significance to this observation?**

**Edit:** For additional clarity, here is a more abstract version of my question:

Consider two disjunctions $D_1$ and $D_2$, both of which are mutually exclusive, such that $D_1:= A \lor B \lor C$ and $D_2:=P \lor Q \lor R$. If we know that $A \rightarrow P$, and $B \rightarrow Q$, given $R$, why can I conclude $R \rightarrow C$? This appears to generalize to any size disjunction (so long as $D_1$ and $D_2$ are the same size and, importantly, mutually exclusive). By "generalize" I mean that if 2 same-sized mutually exclusive disjunctions have $n$ sub-propositions, and I know $n-1$ implications linking them, I can immediately surmise the last implication.

Comment: Frankly speaking, I cannot understand... Yes, trichotomy is an example where the "inclusive" or is used with mutual exclusive cases. No issue here: logic is full of them: $p \lor \lnot p$ is an example.

Comment: About the bijection, I've some doubts: $-1 < 1$ but $(-1)^2 = 1^2$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA sorry, the image did not include the fact that they are all greater than $0$. I edited it to reflect this.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA this post is mostly about how Statement 1 and Statement 2 FIX the claim related to $x=y$

Comment: No mistery here... It is called Replacement (or: Substitution) of equivalents: if $A \equiv B$, then $\varphi[A/p] \equiv \varphi [B/p]$

Comment: And similar for equality: if $x=y$, then $\varphi(x) \leftrightarrow \varphi(y)$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I'm not quite certain I see the connection between my inquiry and the replacement of equivalents. Sorry if I am doing a poor job communicating the question.

Comment: When $x,y > 0$ we have $x < y \leftrightarrow x^2 < y^2$. Then replace into trichotomy. This is what you have drafted with the "bijective picture".

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Everything you say is true, but my question really is not about the specifics of the problem I provided. The question is about proofs that "resemble" the features depicted in the provided problem. I'll try to figure out a better way of abstracting the question (thank you for the help, nonetheless).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Consider two disjunctions $D_1$ and $D_2$, both of which are mutually exclusive, such that $D_1:= A \lor B \lor C$ and $D_2:=P \lor Q \lor R$. If we know that $A \rightarrow P$, and $B \rightarrow Q$, given $R$, why can I conclude $R \rightarrow C$. This appears to generalize to any size disjunction (so long as $D_1$ and $D_2$ are the same size and, importantly, mutually exclusive). By "generalize" I mean that if 2 same-sized mutually exclusive disjunctions have $n$ sub-propositions, and I know $n-1$ implications linking them, I can immediately surmise the last implication.